# How to corrupt certain pages of a pdf

Tags: pdf, file-corruption

I'm looking for a method to purposely corrupt certain pages of a PDF file. I know how to corrupt a PDF as a whole but I want to know if there is a way to corrupt only certain pages.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What are you actually trying to achieve by corrupting certain pages?

Comment: No no it's not an XY problem, my goal is to corrupt certain pages of the pdf. So when we open the pdf those pages wont load, the way a corrupted pdf wouldn't load.